# Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()

Tags: java, scanner

У меня есть такой код.

```
String anun=sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("age:");
int tar=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("email:");
String mail=sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(mail);
System.out.println("email:" + mail);
```

И всегда, когда наступает время для `String mail=sc.nextLine();`, просто пропускается шаг. В чем заключается проблема?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

В этой строке вы считали только число (не учитывая всё, что может идти дальше, включая конец строки):

```
sc.nextInt();
```

Далее при вызове

```
sc.nextLine();
```

Происходит считывание конца строки (начиная от ранее введенного числа и заканчивая переводом строки). Можете добавить дополнительный вызов `sc.nextLine();` после каждого вызова `nextInt();`.