# Запутался в конструкции

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Разработано консольное приложение списка контактов, по заданию реализовал валидацию номера если оно число, но код стал странно работать. Класс MAIN, где и происходит основное меню:

```
do {
        System.out.println("Please select action (I, N, R, L, E, Q): ");
        choice = sc.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();

        switch (choice) {
            case "I":
                cm.loadFromFileAndPrint();
                break;
            case "N":
                String name;
                long number;
                String lengthNum;
                String city;
                do {
                    System.out.print("Name: ");
                    name = sc.nextLine().trim();
                    if (name.length() < 30) {
                        if (cm.isNameExist(name)) break;
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Error: A record with such name already exists!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Name is too big!");
                    }

                } while (true);

                do {
                    System.out.print("Phone number: ");

                    if (sc.hasNextLong()) {
                        number = sc.nextLong();
                        lengthNum = String.valueOf(number);

                        if (lengthNum.length() <= 12 && lengthNum.length() >= 3) {
                            if (cm.isNumberExist(number)) {
                                break;
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Error: A record with such number already exists!");
                            }
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Not valid number!");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Is not a number!");
                        sc.next();
                    }
                } while (true);

                do {
                    System.out.print("City: ");

                    city = sc.next();
                    if (city.length() < 30) break;
                    else {
                        System.out.println("City name should be less than 30 characters");
                    }
                } while (true);

                long id = cm.addContact(new Contact(name, number, city));
                System.out.println("New record with ID  " + id + " has been created!");
                break;
            case "R":
                System.out.print("Record ID: ");
                long idr = Long.parseLong(sc.nextLine());
                cm.deleteContact(idr);
                System.out.println("Record with ID  " + idr + " has been removed!");
                break;
            case "E":
                cm.exportToNewCSVfile("export.csv");
                break;
            case "L":
                Collections.reverse(cm.getContacts());
                cm.printContacts();
                break;
            case "L:NAME":
                Collections.sort(cm.getContacts(), new SortedByName());
                cm.printContacts();
                break;
            case "L:NAME!":
                Collections.sort(cm.getContacts(), new SortedByName().reversed());
                cm.printContacts();
                break;
            case "L:PHONE":
                Collections.sort(cm.getContacts(), new SortedByPhone());
                cm.printContacts();
                break;
            case "L:PHONE!":
                Collections.sort(cm.getContacts(), new SortedByPhone().reversed());
                cm.printContacts();
                break;
            case "L:CITY":
                Collections.sort(cm.getContacts(), new SortedByCity());
                cm.printContacts();
                break;
            case "L:CITY!":
                Collections.sort(cm.getContacts(), new SortedByCity().reversed());
                cm.printContacts();
                break;
        }
    } while (!choice.equals("Q"));
    System.out.println("Bye!");
```

Во время добавления нового контакта - опция "N", пользователь вводит имя, номер, город (город не обязательно вводить). Глюк происходит после добавления города - если его не вводить консоль постоянно в режиме ожидания ввода, если город ввести, то потом 2 раза выводится основное сообщение меню: `System.out.println("Please select action (I, N, R, L, E, Q): ");`
Помогите разобраться где ошибся.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Answer (score 3):

```
    do {
       System.out.print("City: ");
       city = sc.next();
       if (city.length() < 30) break;
       else {
            System.out.println("City name should be less than 30 characters");
       }
    } while (true);
```

При каждом повторении цикла do-while программа сначала выполняет тело цикла, а затем вычисляет условное выражение. Значит

> (город не обязательно вводить).

в данном случае не прокатывает. При любом условии цикл запустится хотяб один раз.
Согласно api класса Scanner метод public Sting next() описывается так:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

что говорит нам - метод может блокироваться при ожидании ввода для сканирования. и.т.д. Потому вы получаете

> если его не вводить консоль постоянно в режиме ожидания ввода

Проблема вывода двух раз System.out.println("Please select action (I, N, R, L, E, Q): ");

связана с api класса Scanner метод public Sting nextLine() описывается так:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that
>   was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line,
>   excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the
>   beginning of the next line. Since this method continues to search
>   through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of
>   the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are
>   present.

что и приводит к ошибке.. сами смотрите:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String caseMY;
    do{
        System.out.print("ВВЕДИТЕ next :");
        caseMY = sc.next().trim().toUpperCase();

        System.out.print("ВВЕДИТЕ lineg:");
        caseMY = sc.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();

    }while(!caseMY.equals("Q"));
}
```

Ну, в общем, как-то так), может Вам поможет мой ответ

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется у вас проблемма в этом участке кода:

```
 System.out.print("City: ");

                    city = sc.next();
                    if (city.length() < 30) break;
                    else {
```

В частности расмотрите работу своего цикла.

Comment: Ведь у вас условие if не может пройти проверку, поставьте break   начале else.

Comment: Да верно, у вас цикл будет работать до тех пор пока, вы не выполните условие If. Я конечно не особо мастер  в java. 
Но вам нужно придумать как пропустить цикл, потому что вам нужно вывести и сообщение. Гм..