# Ошибка в Scanner Java после второго-третьего ввода

Tags: java, scanner

День добрый. Пишу большую программу на Java. Решил применить полученные знания на практике. Программа шашки. В цикле мы набираем координату шашки нашей команды и куда ее передвинуть. Далее будет код из main, в котором после 2-3 прохода Scanner один из двух раз не дает ввести координату с вот таким сообщением (через дебаггер увидел):

> java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=18][match
>   valid=true][need input=false][source
>   closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\ ][decimal
>   separator=\,][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive
>   suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]

Далее сам код

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String old, attack = null;

    decktop desk = new decktop();
    checker check = new checker();
    Usability use = new Usability(desk, check);
    Scanner inw = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner inb = new Scanner(System.in);
    //----------
    desk.create(check);
    desk.vivod();
    while(use.whenEnd()) {
        if (use.whatTeam()) {
            System.out.println("Ходят белые");
            if (use.FirstInput) {
                System.out.print("Введите коодинату белой  шашки:");
                old=(String)inw.next();
                System.out.print("Введите координату атаки: ");
                attack=(String)inw.next();

                use.white(old, attack);                
             } else {
                old=attack;

                System.out.print("Дополнительный ход. Для шашки " + old+ ". Введите координату атаки еще одной шашки: ");
                attack=inw.nextLine();
                use.white(old, attack);

            }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Answer (score 0):

Без полного кода трудно понять, но бросается в глаза:

1. Не надо 2 объекта `Scanner` создавать используйте один и сохраняйте результат в переменные.
2. Зачем приведение типов: `old=(String) inw.next();`?
   У вас метод `next()` и так возвращает `String`:
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()
   Там еще дополнительные моменты с шаблоном разделителя есть, у вас тут нет в нем необходимости, лучше возьмите `nextLine()`. Вот так: `old = inw.nextLine();`
3. Не используйте транслит в коде `desk.vivod();` это очень плохой тон.