# Проясните механизм работы Scanner

Tags: java, scanner

Вот такой код не работает как хочется:

```
public class Dialog {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    static void askWhatToDo (){
        System.out.println("what to do?");
        byte answer = input.nextByte(); //всё хорошо, даёт ввести число
        Dialog.nextOperation();
    }

    static void nextOperation (){
        System.out.println("Input name: ");
        String name = input.nextLine(); //не даёт возможности ввода, просто проскакивает
    }
}
```

Если же я создаю новый объект Scanner в методе nextOperation, то всё в порядке:

```
    static void nextOperation (){
        System.out.println("Input name: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String name = input.nextLine(); //всё работает, ждёт пока я введу строку
    }
```

Почему не подходит уже созданный статический экземпляр объекта Scanner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `next()`, а не `nextLine()`.

`nextLine()` читает c начала до конца текущей строки. А натыкается на символ перевода строки от прошлого ввода(\n)

То есть вы ввели 1 и нажали **Enter**
В итоге получается что вам вернулось 1, а символ \n остался в "буффере".

После вызова `nextLine()` начинает читать с начала и натывается сразу на `\n`. Поэтому и прерывает работу.

[P.S. кстати был уже похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-scanner-nextline)