# Работа метода Scanner.nextInt()

Tags: java, kotlin

Почему появляется сообщение о возникновении `NumberFormatException`? Если использовать `val initialMoney = nextLine().toInt()`, то всё ок!? То есть приходится сначала вводить строку, а только потом преобразовывать её в число. Почему сразу нельзя ввести число и хранить его в переменной???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import java.util.Scanner

fun main() {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)

    var initialMoney = scanner.nextInt()
    val numbers = scanner.nextLine().split(" ")
    for (number in numbers) {
        val digit = number.toInt()
        initialMoney -= digit
        if (initialMoney < 0) {
            println("Error, insufficient funds for purchase. You have ${initialMoney + digit}, but you need $number.")
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Comment: Суть задача неясна из кода. Напишите само задание. Совершенно непонятно зачем вообще делать nextLine, когда есть hextInt и hasNextInt

Answer (score 0):

У вас массив `numbers` содержит пустую строку, поэтому вот здесь

```
val digit = number.toInt()
```

и валится с `NumberFormatException`.

Мне не ясно, что вы там вводите, возможно просто лишние пробелы надо обрезать.