# Почему Scanner.in.nextLine() срабатывает и считывает пустую строку без ввода?

Tags: java

В цикле for() мне нужно делать вводы строк с консоли и добавлять их в массив. По непонятным мне причинам первая итерация проходит, запихивая в массив пустую строку.
До этого я хочу с консоли ввести размер этого массива. Если я это делаю в main() и передаю в функцию размер, то всё в порядке, но я хочу делать это внутри функции. Подскажите в чём причина, что после ввода размера с помощью in.nextInt() считывается пустая строка с помощью in.nextLine() ?

```
public static void Salads() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введи количество салатов - ");
    int quantity = in.nextInt();
    String [] salads = new String [quantity];

    for(int i=0; i < quantity; ++i) {
        System.out.println("размер i в цикле = " + i);
        System.out.print("Введи название салата - ");
        salads[i] = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("первый [0] элеменет в массиве салаты = " + salads[0]);
    }
```

Множество println это я для себя делал, как маркеры

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Comment: Благодарю, да это та же проблема. А решается она только  добавлением дополнительного вызова nextLine(); после каждого вызова nextInt() ? Или есть более правильный способ ? Не судите строго, я пока только учусь =))

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
int quantity = in.nextInt();in.nextLine();
```

Если вы ввели, например `5`, то на самом деле там будет еще символ перевода строки, например `"5\n"`, кроме того, `.nextInt` считает `"5"`, а символ перевода останется, его как раз и получите при вызове `nextLine`

Comment: Благодарю, а его как-то можно обнулить не вызывая дополнительно nextLine(); после вызова nextInt() ?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, то можно, но нужно вместо `nextInt` сразу вызывать `nextLine` и приводить полученную строку в число: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)