# Куда исчезает символ переноса строки при перехвате исключения?

Tags: java, ооп, циклы, исключения, scanner

Господа, есть два стула…, ой т. е. кода. Логика в них примерно одна и та же, но второй работает как по мне странно. А именно: 
В [первом](https://replit.com/@work8play/Programm-1) случае мы присваиваем переменной x произвольное число через метод console.nextInt(), который его считывает до первого "попавшегося на пути" символа переноса строки "\n" (нажатие ENTER после ввода числа). Считал число, присвоил переменной, но в сканере console всё ещё остаётся символ переноса строки "\n", который тянется дальше по программе. И, если после инициализации переменной x не вызвать метод console.nextLine() (который как раз таки скипнет этот самый оставшийся "\n") и написать вместо числа какое-нибудь слово, то условие следующего цикла while (!console.hasNextInt()) [while ("пока там не int")] выдаст false дважды и соответственно фраза "Введите y: " также запринтится дважды. Почему? 
Вот что будет в консоли в начале цикла: "\n"; 
далее мы пишем любое слово и жмём Enter;
 в консоли: "\n"слово"\n";
 метод console.hasNextInt() -> false;
console.nextLine() скипает первый "\n" и на новый виток цикла уже поступает: слово"\n";
 console.hasNextInt() -> false;
 console.nextLine() скипает уже всю строку (слово"\n") и дальше всё работает в штатном режиме, без двойных принтов фразы "Введите y: " ведь в начале каждого последующего ввода у нас уже не будет незримо присутствовать "\n".
Избежать двойного принта в самом начале довольно просто. После инициализации переменной x просто вызвать "в холостую" console.nextLine() и всё; он скипнет этот несчастный "\n".
Суть самого цикла в общем-то заключается в том, чтобы пользователь обязательно ввёл целое число. Просто попробуйте запустить код с комментированным и не комментированным методом **console.nextLine()** после инициализации переменной x, и увидите разницу. Тесты **должны быть** одного вида:
1. какое-то число
2. какое-то слово
Что происходит в первом коде знаю я, знаете теперь  и вы (или уже до этого знали эти нюансы). Однако [второй](https://repl.it/@work8play/Programm-2) код с той же логикой, но там я уже перехватываю исключение, не выдаст двойного принта не зависимо от того, вызову я после int x = console.nextInt(); console.nextLine(); или нет. Без разницы! Вообще. 
Осюда вопрос: **куда исчезает "\n" во втором коде?!**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Comment: Перехват исключения вроде не при чём. Это работа nextInt такая.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что при вызове два раза подряд `nexInt()`, если мы ввели 2 числа (например, `1\n2\n`), то `первый` перенос строки после `второго` `nextInt()` исчезнет (выражаясь вашими словами), а второй останется до будущих считываний.

Comment: Да, вы правы, но это происходит именно при вводе числа во второй разе. А если вылетает исключение? Т. е. пользователь сначала ввёл число, потом вводит чушь? И в консоли следующее: \nчушь\n. То когда это исключение срабатывает, в консоли остаётся: чушь\n    Так?