# Не получается ввести с клавиатуры

Tags: java

Я создал объект класса Scanner, и вызвал 2 раза метод nextFloat(),и когда вызываю метод nextString() то в консоли я ничего не могу вводить. То есть в переменные типа Float я могу ввести, а в переменные типа String уже не получается.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Comment: У вас будет больше шансов получить внятный ответ, если вы покажете свой код, толком объясните, что хотели получить от этого кода, и расскажете, что получается в реальности.

Comment: Потому что после `nextFloat()` нужно еще считывать конец строки, а потом уже ожидать чего-то от `nextLine()`