# Проблема с проверкой в конструктороре - Java

Tags: java

У меня есть конструтор в который значения я буду вводить с клавиатуры, и например я проверяю переменную `waga` на значение, переменая должна быть в нужном диапазоне, и проверка здесь работает отлично. Но я хочу проверить еще одну переменную `bluetooth`, и он должен быть равен только `t` или `n`, в противной случае, должно быть поймано исключение. Но сейчас что бы я не вводил у меня выскакивает это исключение, почему так? И еще такой вопрос почему после первого исключение я должен писать `scanner.nextLine()`, для того что бы оно сьело пустую строку, как она там появляеться?

```
    public KomputerPrzenosny() {
        super();
        this.waga = scanner.nextDouble();
        if (this.waga < 1.2 || this.waga > 3.5)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Waga musi byc z przedzialu 1.2kg do 3.5kg");
        scanner.nextLine();
        this.bateria = scanner.nextLine();
        this.bluetooth = scanner.nextLine();
        if (!this.bluetooth.equals("t") || !this.bluetooth.equals("n"))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bluetooth powinien przyjac wartosc: t lub n");
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Comment: `!this.bluetooth.equals("t") || !this.bluetooth.equals("n")` всегда `true`. Вероятно вы хотели `!this.bluetooth.equals("t") && !this.bluetooth.equals("n")`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, здесь же как раз и есть дополнительный вызов. тут проблема просто в том, что последнее условие всегда true

Comment: @Grundy поэтому возможный дубликат, а не дубликат)) В таком случае это дубликат вопроса [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701409/191482) %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не, наверняка уже были вопросы с такими невозможными условиями, я точно встречал, надо просто поискать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в последнем условии:

```
if (!this.bluetooth.equals("t") || !this.bluetooth.equals("n"))
```

В данном случае оно может вернуть `false` **только** тогда, когда `bluetooth` **одновременно** и `t` и `n`, что довольно тяжело реализовать.

Для решения достаточно заменить `||` на `&&`, в этом случае проверяется, что значение и не `t` и не `n`, что и требовалось по условию.

Comment: я сделал так ```boolean flag = true; if (this.bluetooth.equals("t") || this.bluetooth.equals("n"))
            flag = true;
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bluetooth powinien przyjac wartosc: t lub n");``` Тоже работает, сойдет?

Comment: @kaban.of, здесь добавлена лишняя переменная `flag`, ее можно было не добавлять. А почему просто не заменить `||` на `&&`?

Comment: Ну я теперь заменю, просто раньше не знал как исправить, и придумал так сделать