# Почему не выполняется условие ? Java

Tags: java, строки, if

Дана задача: Написать программу, которая переводит значение угла из градусов в радианы, и наоборот, в зависимости от символа при вводе.

Например: 45.00D означает значение в градусах, а 45.00R - в радианах.

После ввода числа, программа не даёт ввести символ и сразу переходит к выполнению условия error.

Код программы :

```
package NIIT;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RadianConvertor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Value");
        double value = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter degrees or radian");
        String letter = scan.nextLine();
   
        double Pi = 3.14159265359;
    
        if (letter.equals("D") || letter.equals("d")) {
            System.out.println(value * Pi / 180);
        }
        if (letter.equals("R") || letter.equals("r")) {
            System.out.println(value * 180 / Pi);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Результат выполнения :

```
Value
12
Enter degrees or radian
Error
    
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Ваши условия звучат так: "введённая буква должна быть и заглавной и строчной одновременно". Вы понимаете что это невыполнимое условие? Это как сказать, что число должно быть и положительным и отрицательным одновременно

Comment: Спасибо большое . Поправил ! Но это не решило мою проблему .

Comment: Я думаю проблема в функции scanner во втором случае , потому что он даже не переходит к ней . Но что конкретно не так понять не могу .

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/269359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следует заменить `&&` на `||` ,

тк `&&` - означает `И`, а letter не может быть одновременно `d` и `D`, поэтому Вам нужен `||` (`ИЛИ`)

Хотя я бы на твоем месте сделал следующее:
`letter.toLowerCase().equals("d")`

```
package NIIT;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RadianConvertor {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Value");
        double value = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine()); // Лучше nextLine, и затем parseDouble
        System.out.println("Enter degrees or radian");
        String letter = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close(); // Лучше закрывать Scanner;

        double Pi = Math.PI; // Лучше использовавть уже готовый PI
        
        if(letter.toLowerCase().equals("d")) {  // toLowerCase() заменяет все символы на строчные
            System.out.println(value*Pi/180);
        } else if(letter.toLowerCase().equals("r")) {
            System.out.println(value*180/Pi);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё по делу, кроме одного совета: `Scanner` открытый на `System.in` _не нужно_ закрывать, так как закроется и `System.in`.