# Java; Метод scanner читает пустую строку

Tags: java, scanner

---

ПРОБЛЕМА

---

Разбираю пример кода на java.
Опыта нет совсем.

На шаге 15 (см. ниже) метод scanner почему-то не читает введённый символ "+",
вместо него он читает пустую строку,
и переходит к строке кода со словом default в конце блока switch

---

ВОПРОС:

---

В чём ошибся в расписывании кода по шагам?
Я читал советы, как исправить код,
но хочу понимать, почему этот код не работает,
а не просто лишь бы работало скопировать рабочий код.

---

Как я понимаю процесс выполнения этого кода по шагам:

---

0. создаётся объект scanner
1. В консоли метод print пишет сообщение "Введите 1 число: "
2. Перевод строки не указывается
3. выполняется метод scaner
   курсор в консоли моргает, приглашая ввести число
4. пользователь вводит число (например, 5) и нажимает enter
   получается, пользователь вводит 5/n
   а вовсе не просто 5
   этот важный момент я понимаю
5. метод scanner читает введённые символы до знака перевода строки, т.е. до /n
6. прочитанное значение 5 присваивается переменной num1
7. метод print выполняет перенос строки, т.к. каретка (курсор) остановился перед знаком /n
   и печатает, что ему велит код "Введите 2 число: "
   перенос строки не требуется,
   курсор стоит в конце пустой строки без символа переноса строки
8. выполняется метод scaner
   курсор в консоли моргает, приглашая ввести число
9. пользователь вводит число (например, 8) и нажимает enter
   получается, пользователь вводит 8/n
10. метод scanner читает введённые символы до знака перевода строки, т.е. до /n
11. прочитанное значение 8 присваивается переменной num2
12. объявляется переменная res
13. метод print выполняет перенос строки, т.к. каретка (курсор) остановился перед знаком /n
    и печатает, что ему велит код "Действие: "
    перенос строки не требуется,
    курсор стоит в конце пустой строки без символа переноса строки
14. выполняется метод scaner
    курсор в консоли моргает, приглашая ввести действие
15. пользователь вводит действие (например, +) и нажимает enter
    получается, пользователь вводит +/n

---

КОД:

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Условные конструкции switch-case
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите 1 число: ");
    int num1 = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Введите 2 число: ");
    int num2 = scanner.nextInt();

    int res;

    System.out.print("Действие: ");
    String action = scanner.nextLine();

    switch (action) {
        case "+":
            res = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println("Результат: " + res);
            break;
        case "-":
            res = num1 - num2;
            System.out.println("Результат: " + res);
            break;
        case "*":
            res = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println("Результат: " + res);
            break;
        case "/":
            if(num2 == 0)
                System.out.println("Error");
            else {
                res = num1 / num2;
                System.out.println("Результат: " + res);
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Вы что-то не то ввели.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вывод и ввод производятся в *разные* потоки ввода/вывода: `System.out` и `System.in`, которые отображаются в одной консоли, поэтому пункты 13-14 не важны.

В реальности происходит следующее:

> 10. метод `scanner.nextInt()` читает введённые символы до знака перевода строки, т.е. до `\n`
> 11. прочитанное значение 8 присваивается переменной `num2`
>     То есть, символ `\n` остаётся *непрочитанным* в потоке `System.in`.

Соответственно, при вызове `scanner.nextLine()` считывается *ближайшая* строка (*включающая* символ `\n`) -- то есть, *пустая* строка.  Данные, которые ввёл пользователь после подсказки `Действие:` , остаются в потоке ввода *непрочитанными*.

В этом можно убедиться, если добавить вывод переменной `action` в `default` части оператора `switch`:

```
    default:
        System.out.println("Вы что-то не то ввели. '" + action + "'");
// -> Вы что-то не то ввели. ''
```

Аналогично, если пользователь будет разделять числа пробелами и нажмёт Enter после ввода действия, этот пробел будет cчитан в переменную `action`, и также выполнится `default:`:

```
// -> Вы что-то не то ввели. ' +'
```

---

Это известная, можно сказать, классическая проблема работы с консольным вводом/выводом.  Решается она несколькими способами:

1. Вместо `scanner.nextLine` использовать `scanner.next()` -- тогда действие прочитается без пробельных символов.
2. Вместо `scanner.nextInt()` считывать ввод пользователя *построчно* и парсить прочитанную строку, например: `int num1 = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());`
3. Пропустить пустую строку после второго `nextInt`:

```java
int num1 = scanner.nextInt();
int num2 = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine();
String action = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: Спасибо. 
Вот эта идея всё бы прекрасно объясняла, но
почему такой проблемы не появляется в этом коде, когда считываются 2 числа?

Comment: Проблема появляется только при переходе от считывания числа к считыванию строкового типа данных.

Comment: При считывании двух чисел, разделённых `\n` или другими пробельными символами, эти пробельные символы будут игнорироваться в методе `nextInt() / nextFoo()`, а `nextLine` за них "зацепляется", и получается пустая строка.

Comment: Спасибо, 
это своё предположение, я и хотел подтвердить, сказанное прямым текстом опытным программистом.