# Во время ввода string переменных в массив с клавиатуры пропускается ячейка массива с 0-ым индексом

Tags: java, массивы, строки, scanner

Суть программы: пользователь вводит сначала количество имен (quantity_players), которое он хочет поместить в массив, а потом начинает их перечислять.
Во время перечисления возникает баг. В массиве не заполняется ячейка с индексом 0. В выводе это отображается как подряд идущая строка Enter name: Enter name: и только с индекса массива 1 идет заполнение. Выводится тоже первый номер пустой.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Task3 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //game();
        users_name();
    }
    public static void users_name(){

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter quantity players: ");
        int quantity_players=input.nextInt();

        String users_name[]=new String[quantity_players];
        for (int i=0;i<quantity_players;i++){
            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            users_name[i]=input.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i=0;i<quantity_players;i++){
            System.out.printf("%d. player: %s\n",i+1,users_name[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В текущем варианте вы считываете только число без анализа конца строки пришедшей из консоли данных

```
int quantity_players=input.nextInt();
```

В это варианте вы считаете всю строку из консоли

```
int quantity_players = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```