# Вывод и сортировка массива

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Мне нужно отсортировать ввести текстовый массив с клавиатуры и отсортировать все слова по возрастанию. Проблема: я ввожу размер массива с клавиатуры, но оно выводит на один меньше и сортирует неправильно. Помогите исправить)
Вот код:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите размер массива: ");
        int size  = sc.nextInt();
        String[] array = new String[size];
        sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите несколько слов: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = sc.nextLine();       
            }
        System.out.println("Введенный массив");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println("Отсортированный массив");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
        }
    
        }
    public void sort(String[] array)
    {
        Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Answer (score 0):

Первый `nextLine()` в цикле поглощал перевод строки после `nextInt()`.
Объект сканера нужно создать заново. Сортировка работает.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите размер массива: ");
        int size  = sc.nextInt();
        String[] array = new String[size];
        sc  = new Scanner(System.in); // создайте новый сканер
        System.out.println("Введите несколько слов: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Введенный массив");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        Arrays.sort(array);
        System.out.println("Отсортированный массив");
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + array[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

```
Введите размер массива: 6
Введите несколько слов: 
Иван
родил
девчонку
велел
тащить
пеленку
Введенный массив
 Иван родил девчонку велел тащить пеленку
Отсортированный массив
 Иван велел девчонку пеленку родил тащить
```

Дополнение. Порядок сортировки по длине слов можно переопределить через

```
Arrays.sort(array, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
```

Comment: но оно неправильно сортирует: девчонку > пеленку

Comment: @VWinner почему??? Сортировка по возрастанию "п" > "д", поэтому сначала "д", потом "п"

Comment: а мне кажется, что задача состоит в сортировке по количестве символов в слове

Comment: @VWinner что значит кажется?

Comment: в задаче сказано по возрастанию, это можно воспринимать как по возрастанию числа символов в слове, а можно как вы. Я подумал, что по количеству символов

Comment: @АлексейР не надо пересоздавать объект, достаточно написать так         int size  = sc.nextInt();
 sc.nextLine();

Comment: @VWinner добавил ниже кода сортировку по длине

Comment: Всем спасибо, решил проблему

Comment: Вопрос закрыт))

Answer (score 0):

массив имеет 1 интересное свойствo:

```
String[] abc = new String[15];
```

Вроде-бы всё правильно, но если потом написать:

```
String[15] = "hello";
```

То выбьет ошибку. Всё потому-что при создании массива, отсчёт массива будет на 1 меньше. Например:

```
int listLength = n;

String[] list = new String[listLength];

System.out.println(list[listLength-1]); //последнее значение массива
```

Comment: Вы хотите рассказать, что нумерация массивов идёт с нуля. Это хорошо, но к вопросу отношения не имеет.

Comment: В программе нет проблем с диапазоном массива. Там, всем известная проблема с методом `nextInt()` класса `Scanner`. Просто, после вызова метода `nextInt()` нужно вызвать метод `nextLine()` и нет необходимости, пересоздавать объект `Scanner`