# Обработка исключения на ввод пользователя в Java

Tags: java, filewriter

Не могу продумать грамотное построение конструкции для обработки того, что я в вводе при запуске программы могу указать путь к файлу всё, что угодно, а ошибку он не выкидывает. (запись в файл списков).

```java
case 8:
    System.out.println("Введите путь и имя файла: " + scanner.nextLine());
    String filePath = scanner.nextLine();
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath)) {
        for (Point line : points) {
            writer.write(line + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        System.out.println("Данные успешно записаны в файл.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка при записи данных в файл: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    
    break;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Файл создаётся в репозитории проекта, но не видим внутри проекта в Eclipse + не имеет расширения, хотя текстовые редакторы (Notepad) содержимое видят

Comment: "Всё, что угодно" - нет, это не так. Файлы с именами `abc`, `1232` и прочими подобными - это вполне себе файлы, даже без расширений, поэтому ошибки и нет. Она возникнет, только если имя файла будет некорректным с точки зрения файловой системы. Например, будет содержать `:` в названии. Если вам не нравится возможность ввода таких файлов, то можете вручную проверить наличие расширения простым `lastIndexOf(".")`. Хотя это не спасёт от ввода каких-нибудь безумных расширений, на этот случай можете ещё проверять расширение, например, чтобы оно было только `.txt`.

Comment: Ошибка не обрабатывается потому что файл создается, так как вы не вводите путь к файлу, попробуйте ввести следующий путь и ошибка воспроизведется - A:/file.txt

Comment: Не понимаю способ решения проблемы через lastIndexOf(".")

Comment: А какой смысл сканирования строки в `System.out.println("Введите путь и имя файла: " + scanner.nextLine());`? Если файлы успешно создаются, какую ошибку вы ожидаете?  Если у файла обязателььно расширение, можете его добавить самостоятельно.

Comment: Программа сразу выдаёт ошибку без этой строчки, не давая ничего сделать

Comment: Понятно, здесь ещё и классический дубликат: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileWriter` выдаст ошибку только в том случае, если имя файла не будет корректным для файловой системы. То есть для того, чтобы было выброшено исключение `IOException`, имя файла либо должно содержать запрещённые символы типа `<`, `>` и прочих, либо являться некорректным путём типа `ABC:/text.txt`.

Файлы же без расширений - как `asd`, который вы ввели в качестве теста - это обычные файлы для файловой системы, поэтому ошибка и не возникает.

Вы можете самостоятельно проверить наличие расширения у файла. Сделать это можно по-разному. Например, так:

```
int lastIndexOf = filePath.lastIndexOf(".");
if (lastIndexOf == -1 || filePath.substring(lastIndexOf + 1).isEmpty()) {
    // something
}
```

Внутри этого блока `if` вы можете бросить своё собственное исключение и отлавливать его в `try` вместе с `IOException`, или сделать как-то иначе.

Однако это не спасает от сомнительных расширений типа `.abcdef`. На этот случай можете составить список "разрешённых" расширений файлов:

```
List<String> extensions = List.of(
    "txt",
    "xml",
    "json"
); // список можно продолжать
```

Тогда проверку корректности имени файла можно усовершенствовать следующим образом:

```
int lastIndexOf = filePath.lastIndexOf(".");
if (lastIndexOf == -1 || !extensions.contains(filePath.substring(lastIndexOf + 1))) {
    // something
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Уже завтра реализую это и оставлю комментарий !!!!