# Не могу реализовать метод

Tags: java, массивы

```java
import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("На какое кол-во человек необходимо разделить счет?");
        int peopleNum = s.nextInt();
        if (peopleNum == 1 || peopleNum < 1) {
            System.out.println("Введите корректное число");
        }
        System.out.println("Введите название товара и сумму");
        
        String[] menuArray = new String[100];
        double[] sumArray = new double[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < menuArray.length; i++) {
            menuArray[i] = s.nextLine();
            for (int b = 0; b < sumArray.length; b++) {
                sumArray[b] = s.nextInt();
            }
            if (menuArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("завершить")) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь вводил название товара и сумму, товар и сумма должны добавляться в массив.

Затем надо, чтобы этот цикл повторялся до тех пор, пока я не напишу `завершить` в консоли.

Далее мне надо будет показать то, что записал в массив `String`, и сложить сумму, которая должна быть в массиве `double`, эту сумму поделить на число, введенное в `peopleNum`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Почему не можете?

Comment: больше не не могу, а не получается(

Comment: Почему не получается?

Comment: напиши, в чем конкретно что-то не получается. пока выглядит так, что ты просто закинул, типа, сделайте...

Comment: Пользователь не хочет ничего вводить?  Оказывает сопротивление?  А если серьёзно, как вы вводите товар и сумму, в один массив или разные?  Вы знаете, что _массивы_ в Java имеют фиксированную длину?  Если хотите, чтобы размер массива увеличивался, следует использовать список ('List').

Comment: Что у вас не получается? Помните, что **учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при  решении задачи (для этого нажмите [edit]). Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: добавил код, надеюсь донесу мысль которую хотел реализовать

Comment: Я хотел чтобы пользователь вводил название товара, после чего указывал сумму и так до тех пор пока, пока я не напишу в консоль завершить. Далее мне надо будет показать то что записал в массив String и сложить сумму которая должна быть в массиве double, эту сумму поделить на число веденное в peopleNum.

Comment: По вашему коду: 1) не нужен импорт `SQLOutput` 2) При вводе `peopleNum` нужен цикл, пока не будет введено корректное значение, иначе останется любое некорректное. 3) Значение `peopleNum` после ввода нигде не используется, создаются массивы на 100 элементов. 4) Массив сумм объявлен как `double[]`, но вводятся в него целые числа 5) Классическая ошибка при вводе: одновременное использование `Scanner::nextLine` и `Scanner::nextInt`, см. [Особенности использования `scanner.nextLine()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/) или любой из нескольких сотен дубликатов.

Comment: О, ещё упустил _вложенный цикл_ при вводе сумм.  Зачем вы пытаетесь ввести для каждого товара, которых у вас 100 штук, по 100 сумм, какой в этом смысл, если массив сумм один, и при вводе старые значения будут перетираться.

Comment: Разрешено ли вам пользоваться списками (коллекциями) в качестве _динамических массивов_, которые могут менять размер?

Comment: Да, в целом загвоздка только в создании массива.

Answer (score 1):

Возможный вариант решения с устранением ошибок в коде вопроса:

- Ввод `peopleNum` в цикле, пока не будет введено корректное число.
- Использование `Scanner::nextLine` + `Integer.parseInt` / `Double.parseDouble` для ввода пользователя (при таком способе десятичным разделителем всегда в числах будет точка, независимо от локали); строки и числа всегда вводятся с новой строки.
- Подсчёт количества пунктов меню при вводе в отдельной переменной `count`, которое не может превышать заранее заданного ограничения (`max = 100`).
- Использование форматированного вывода `System.out.printf`

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("На какое количество человек необходимо разделить счет (не менее 2)?");

        int peopleNum;
        while ((peopleNum = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())) < 2) {
            System.out.println("Введите корректное число");
        }
        int max = 100;
        System.out.println("Введите название товара и сумму, не более " + max + " значений, или \"завершить\"");
        
        String[] items = new String[max];
        double[] amounts = new double[max];
        int count = 0;
        String input;
        // ввод
        while (count < max && !"завершить".equalsIgnoreCase(input = scan.nextLine())) {
            items[count] = input;
            amounts[count] = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
            count++;
            System.out.println("Введите следующий товар и сумму или \"завершить\" для окончания ввода");
        }
        // вывод и вычисление общей суммы
        double total = 0d;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d. %s: %.2f%n", i + 1, items[i], amounts[i]);
            total += amounts[i];
        }
        System.out.printf("Общая сумма: %.2f, средняя сумма на одного: %.2f%n", total, total / peopleNum);        
    }
}
```

---

Небольшой пример использования стандартных возможностей Java (списки, кортежи, Stream API)

Код для решения данной задачи можно немного упростить, заменив обычные массивы с фиксированной длиной `item`, `amounts` списком `List`.

Размер списка будет автоматически увеличиваться при вводе новых данных, и не нужно будет вводить и проверять ограничения на максимальную длину в виде `max = 100`.

Также вместо двух отдельных списков следует использовать отдельный класс с полями "название" и "сумма", для чего в частности удобно использовать кортежи `record`.
Для вычисления суммы элементов списка можно использовать Stream API.

Вариант решения:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass {
    
    // кортеж для "строк" данных: название пункта меню и сумма 
    record Item(String name, double amount){}
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("На какое количество человек необходимо разделить счет (не менее 2)?");

        int peopleNum;
        while ((peopleNum = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())) < 2) {
            System.out.println("Введите корректное число");
        }
        System.out.println("Введите название товара и сумму, или \"завершить\"");
        
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>(); // один список вместо двух массивов
        String input;
        // ввод
        while (!"завершить".equalsIgnoreCase(input = scan.nextLine())) {
            items.add(new Item(input, Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine())));
            System.out.println("Введите следующий товар и сумму или \"завершить\" для окончания ввода");    
        }
        // вывод и вычисление общей суммы
        double total = items.stream().mapToDouble(Item::amount).sum();
        items.forEach(System.out::println);
        System.out.printf("Общая сумма: %.2f, средняя сумма на одного: %.2f%n", total, total / peopleNum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример того, как можно это сделать:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("На какое кол-во человек необходимо разделить счет?");
        int peopleNum = scanner.nextInt();

        while (peopleNum <= 1) {
            System.out.println("Введите корректное число (больше 1):");
            peopleNum = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        scanner.nextLine(); // Очистка буфера

        String[] menuArray = new String[100];
        double[] sumArray = new double[100];
        int itemCount = 0; // Счётчик товаров

        System.out.println("Введите название товара и его сумму через пробел или 'завершить' для окончания ввода:");
        while (true) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if ("завершить".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                break; // Завершаем цикл, если пользователь ввёл "завершить"
            }

            String[] parts = input.split(" ");
            if (parts.length != 2) {
                System.out.println("Некорректный ввод, попробуйте ещё раз:");
                continue;
            }

            String itemName = parts[0];
            double itemSum;

            try {
                itemSum = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Сумма должна быть числом, попробуйте ещё раз:");
                continue;
            }

            menuArray[itemCount] = itemName;
            sumArray[itemCount] = itemSum;
            itemCount++;

            if (itemCount >= menuArray.length) {
                System.out.println("Достигнут предел товаров!");
                break; // Завершить цикл, если достигнут предел массива
            }
        }

        double totalSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            totalSum += sumArray[i]; // Суммирование стоимости товаров
            System.out.println("Товар: " + menuArray[i] + ", Сумма: " + sumArray[i]);
        }

        double dividedSum = totalSum / peopleNum;
        System.out.printf("Общая сумма: %.2f\n", totalSum);
        System.out.printf("Каждый человек должен заплатить: %.2f\n", dividedSum);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: GPT не использовался

Comment: А как вы тогда даёте за несколько часов по 10 ответов? По [tag:java], [tag:c++], [tag:c#] и [tag:vk]

Comment: Просто нечего делать вот и раздаю ответы