# Выдает исключение NumberFormatException, хотя вводится число

Tags: java, scanner

Код выдает исключение `NumberFormatException`, хотя вводится число.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class praktika_1_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        String arr[] = s.split(" ");

        int t[] = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            t[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
        }

        int a[] = new int[arr.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i+1] = a[i] + t[i];
        }

        String ans = "";
        for(int i = 0; i <a.length; i++) {
            ans += Integer.toString(a[i]) + " ";
        }
        System.out.print(ans);
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос описание работы кода. Что он делает? Что вы вводите? В какой строке ошибка? [edit]. И отформатируйте код нормально.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/%d0%9e%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-scanner-nextline)

Answer (score 0):

Вы натолкнулись на классическую "проблему" новичков, указанную в вопросе-дубликате: [Особенности использования `scanner.nextLine()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/), так как использовали `Scanner::nextLine` *после* `Scanner::nextInt`.

На самом деле в представленном коде происходит следующее:

```java
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);  // создали сканер ввода, ок
int n=sc.nextInt();          // прочитали число _без чтения перевода строки_
String s =sc.nextLine();     // прочитали **пустую** строку
String arr[]=s.split(" ");   // получили массив с одной пустой строкой [""]
int t[]=new int[n];          // успешно создали массив n чисел
for(int i=0; i<n;i++) {
    t[i]=Integer.parseInt(arr[i]); // NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
}
// ...
```

Если бы вдруг исключение `NumberFormatException` было перехвачено и обработано, то при попытке обратиться к следующему элементу массива `arr` произошёл бы выход за пределы массива, если бы `n > 1`.

Очевидное решение данной проблемы -- не смешивать `nextInt` и `nextLine`, тем  более, что для заполнения массива целых чисел `t` достаточно вызвать `nextInt` известное число раз.

```java
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
int t[] = new int[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    t[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
int a[] = new int[t.length + 1];
// ...
```