# Пропускается String переменная,, программа заканчивается на System.out.println("Действие: ")

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MMain{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Первое число: ");
        int first = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Второе: ");
        int Second = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Действие: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(123 + name);

        if (Objects.equals(name, "Умножить")){
            int result1 = Second * first;
            System.out.println(result1);
        }
        if (Objects.equals(name, "сложить")){
            int result2 = Second + first;
            System.out.println(result2);
        }

        if (Objects.equals(name, "вычитание")){
            int result3 = Second - first;
            System.out.println(result3);
        }

        if (Objects.equals(name, "деление")){
            int result4 = Second / first;
            System.out.println(result4);
        }



}
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Особенности использования scanner.nextLine()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499681/)

Comment: Чтобы ваш код заработал, вместо `in.nextLine()` просто используйте `in.next()`, тем более что вы считываете одиночное слово - название операции.